# Getting phone numbers from Facebook synced / "Unified Info" address book contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, abaddressbook

I need to be able to read the contacts' phone number from the user's address book. The problem is that if the user has chosen to sync these contacts via Facebook, they are no longer accessible via the following code (which does work for non-synced contacts):

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
DLog(@"Found %ld phones", ABMultiValueGetCount(phones));
for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
{        
    CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
    CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
    NSString *phoneLabel =(__bridge NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);
    NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
    CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
    CFRelease(locLabel);
    DLog(@"  - %@ (%@)", phoneNumber, phoneLabel);
    [numbersArr addObject:phoneNumber];
}
```

The log result is `[Line 126] Found 0 phones`

I have tried to use `CFArrayRef userNumbers = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumbers);`
, but this also returns nothing: `[Line 118] Got user numbers: (null)`

So I tried to dig into the social profiles, and this also returns nothing!

```
// Try to get phone numbers from social profile
        ABMultiValueRef profiles = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
        CFIndex multiCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(profiles);
        for (CFIndex i=0; i<multiCount; i++) {
            NSDictionary* profile = (__bridge NSDictionary*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(profiles, i);
            NSLog(@"TESTING - Profile: %@", profile);

        }
        DLog(@"Got profiles: %@", profiles);
        CFRelease(profiles);
```

Yet the log entry is:
`[Line 161] Got profiles: ABMultiValueRef 0x1ddbb5c0 with 0 value(s)`

If the above results are all not yielding me anything, how am I supposed to know they're a Facebook user & get their phone info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple Support:

> We do not have any APIs that will return a unified Address Book
>   contact. However, you can retrieve phone numbers of contacts that
>   appear as unified in Contacts on your device by first using
>   ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople to retrieve all linked contacts,
>   then iterating through these contacts to fetch their respective phone
>   numbers. Note that phone numbers that do not appear in the UI in
>   Contacts will not be returned by Address Book APIs. See below for a
>   snippet of code that will allow you to do so:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

{

//Fetch all linked contacts

CFArrayRef linkedPerson = ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person);

//Iterate through each linked contact to fetch the phone numbers

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(linkedPerson); i++)

{

ABRecordRef contact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(linkedPerson,i);

ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(contact, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++)

{

CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);

CFStringRef number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

CFRelease(label);

CFRelease(number);

}

CFRelease(multi);

}

CFRelease(linkedPerson);

return YES;
```